# Solve for u $ \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}} = \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} $

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve for u

$ \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}} = \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} $

my teacher solve this equation and gets

$ u = \frac{1}{2\mu} \frac{ \partial p }{\partial x} y^{2} +Ay + B $

I cant seem to get the same answer,

From  here, $ \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}} = \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} $

I would integrate and get

$ \partial u = \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{ \partial p}{\partial x} y^{2}
+Ay $

and than integrate again and get

$ u = \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{ \partial p}{\partial x} y^{2} +Ay +B $

am missing the 2 ?

any help appreciated.

Comment: Your first integration is incorrect.  Additionally, integrating $\partial^2 u / \partial y^2$ gives you $\partial u / \partial y$, not "$\partial u$".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we assumed that $p$ does not depend on $y$.
Then $\frac{1}{\mu}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$ is constant with respect to $y$ call it  $K$. You just get the ordinary equation:
$y''=K$ hence $y'=Ky+A$ and as $\int y dy=y^2/2+const$ you get $y=Ky^2/2+Ay+B$

Answer (score 0):

We have for the first integral
$$ \int \frac{\partial_x p}{\mu}  dy =  \frac{\partial_x p}{\mu}  \int dy =  \frac{\partial_x p}{\mu} y + A $$
Then the second
$$ \int \left ( \frac{\partial_x p}{\mu} y + A \right ) dy= \frac{\partial_x p}{\mu} \int  y \, dy + A\int  dy = \frac{\partial_x p}{\mu} \frac{ y^2}{2} +Ay+ B $$

Comment: I dont quite follow your notation. I have not seen it like this, so dont understand

Comment: Do you know how to integrate? What notation do you use, I believe the notation is standard...